# Power Automate (MS Flow) Error: "Something went wrong. The requested approval is not accessible to the caller." How do I fix this?

Tags: power-automate, microsoft365

My user tries to access Microsoft Power Automate (Flow) approvals via email notifications that the Flow sends to them. When clicking on the approval, they get an error "Something went wrong. The requested approval is not accessible to the caller." When directly accessing their approvals at us.flow.microsoft.com > Action items > Approvals, they only see approvals up to January. The same approvals are working for other users. How do I fix approval access?

I tried having the user login via an incognito tab. I also checked whether the user still has MS PA licenses assigned to them, and they seem to be correct (the user has MS 365 E1, MS 365 Business Premium, and MS Power Automate Free).

Comment: So you have the ability to raise the issue directly with Microsoft? That’s what I’d do.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the what was causing the issue for our user. The user had a duplicate enterprise microsoft account, so both were being sent the email notification about the approvals, but only the duplicate account was being given access to them. Removing the duplicate account fixed the issue.

If we had had two users with the same name & neither can be deleted, another solution would've been to change how the approvals are routed (ie. by email instead of name.)